# is it possible to use `with expressions` for a record with custom properties

Tags: c#, .net-core

is it possible to use `with expressions` for a record with custom properties?

```
public record Person
{
    public string LastName { get; }
    public string FirstName { get; }
    public Person(string first, string last) => (FirstName, LastName) = (first, last);
}
```

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var p = new Person("adam","smith");
    // var p2 = p with { first = "joe" };  // error CS0117: 'Person' does not contain a definition for 'first'
    // var p3 = p with { FirstName = "joe" }; // error CS0200: Property or indexer 'Person.FirstName' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#record-types

Comment: *Other* [examples](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/#records) [...](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/c-9-0-on-the-record/) show them declared with the `init;` accessor. Have you tried that? The one you linked needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the init accessor, check the below example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var c1 = new Candidate("Donald","Trump");          
        var c2 = new Candidate("Donald", "Trump");
        var c3 = c1 with { Surname = "Duck" };
    }
}
public record Candidate
{
    public string FirstName { get; init; }
    public string Surname { get; init; }
    public Candidate(string Fname, String Sname) => (Fname, Sname) = (FirstName, Surname);
}
```

As an aside, if you get the following error after using Init, there is a day 0 bug:

predefined type 'System.Runtime.compilerServices.IsexternalInit is not defined or imported'

If so you need to paste in the following namespace/class into your solution:

```
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{    
public class IsExternalInit { }
}
```

As an final aside, you can cut your code down massively by using positional records as shown below, that way you do not need a constructor or any properties:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        var c1 = new Candidate("Donald", "Trump");            
        Concsole.ReadLine();
    }
}
record Candidate(string FirstName, string Surname);
```

The above example will auto set init, be aware though records created without an access modifier default to public, not private like classes.

Answer (score 0):

The properties need to be declared with `init;`

```
public record Person
{
    public string LastName { get; init; }
    public string FirstName { get; init; }
    public Person(string first, string last) => (FirstName, LastName) = (first, last);
}
```